# Is the resulting accuracy on matrix manipulation any ill-logical?

Tags: octave

```
octave:1> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

octave:2> B = pinv (A)

octave:3> I = eye (size (A))
ans =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1

octave:4> I2 = A * B
ans =

   0.83333   0.33333  -0.16667
   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333
  -0.16667   0.33333   0.83333

octave:5> A2 = A * I2
ans =

   1.00000   2.00000   3.00000
   4.00000   5.00000   6.00000
   7.00000   8.00000   9.00000
```

Why could the final Step 5 result in the perfect accuracy although the previous Step 4 in the unforgiving accuracy?

#### @EDIT

```
octave:6> format long

octave:7> I2
I2 =

   0.833333333333332   0.333333333333332  -0.166666666666666
   0.333333333333332   0.333333333333333   0.333333333333334
  -0.166666666666668   0.333333333333333   0.833333333333334

octave:8> A2
A2 =

   0.999999999999993   1.999999999999997   3.000000000000005
   3.999999999999982   4.999999999999992   6.000000000000014
   6.999999999999972   7.999999999999987   9.000000000000021
```

Comment: It's not perfect accuracy. You just can't see the non-zero decimal points because of your display format.

Comment: Both are much more precise than shown, but rounded for purposes of display. Both are also [likely inaccurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), but with the details of the inaccuracy similarly hidden by display rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result does have errors, it's just that your display settings are such that everything is rounded to 4 decimal places (`format short`). If we change the display format (`format long`), we can see the errors:

```
format long

A * I2

%   0.999999999999990   1.999999999999998   3.000000000000007
%   3.999999999999978   4.999999999999993   6.000000000000017
%   6.999999999999965   7.999999999999987   9.000000000000027
```

Alternately, you can use `num2str` to show any arbitrary number of places after the decimal point.

```
% Show 32 places after the decimal point
num2str(A * I2, 32)
```

As for why `A * pinv(A) * A` is approximately equal to `A`, that is one of the defining properties of the [Moore–Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) computed by `pinv`.

[image]

Comment: Why is A2 derived from very inaccurate I2 still greatly accurate ?

Comment: @sof Added a link describing the properties of the pseudo-inverse. What you are seeing is one of the 4 criteria of the pseudo-inverse.